# how to customize django model message for email

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-model-field

I created User model in Django as:

```
email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name="Email Address", unique=True, null=True, blank=True)
```

When I try to register user with same email it show message **user with this Email Address  already exist**, how can I customize this message to **User with this email exist**

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding of the problem, below answer should solve the issue

```py
models.EmailField(
    verbose_name="Email Address", unique=True, null=True, blank=True,
    error_messages={
        'unique': "User with this email already exists.",
    }
)
```

Comment: Thanks for repose, is it ask for new migrations?

Comment: yes, it will ask for a migration

Answer (score 1):

You can use `unique` attribute of error messages dict and customize it according to your custom message **(User with this email exist)** so:

```py
class User(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name="Email Address", unique=True,
        error_messages={
            'unique': 'User with this email exists.',
        }
    )
```

Comment: Thanks for repose, Thanks for repose, is it ask for new migrations?

Comment: any customize solution for this?

Comment: @AyazKhan If possible, try to create new migration, I assume you know that, It will work.

Comment: application is deploy on server and it is difficult for us to make migrations there

Comment: @AyazKhan So do you want to change this message in admin site or also in frontend? Did you use any form in forms.py? You can also customize that.

Comment: in frontend side we are using react

Comment: @Ayaz That's ok I mean where you want to change default message in admin site or in some form, if any form so please also edit the question with it.

Comment: i also validate user name in sterilizer but email validation doesnot  work there

Comment: i want to change this from backend side

Comment: @AyazKhan You mean only in admin site yes, for staff?

Comment: no when user post request again for new user registration with same email, then in response it will get this error **User with this email already exists** instead this **user with this Email Address already exist**

Comment: @AyazKhan share your relevant code by editing the question.